# How to export Socket.io instance on other files of the project

Tags: node.js, server, socket.io, export, emit

I'm kinda new to Web Dev, especially in node and I'm struggling with socket.io.
The problem is that I need to export my "io" in an other file to emit messages but it's not working, cause I probably do it the wrong way.

I've tried many of the stackOverflow solutions, but didnt manage to succeed.

The two files are server.js, where is the config of the socket:

```
let server = http.createServer(app);
let io_fin=io_test.listen(server);
module.exports= io_test;
```

and in the same file, my "emit request" is working:

```
io_fin.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('an user connected');

    socket.emit('chat message', 'TESTING');
  });
```

In the other file, I've got this import :

```
let yoyo = require('socket.io');
```

and I'm try to emit like this:

```
yoyo.emit('chat message', 'TEST2');
```

And the api is crashing saying "yoyo.emit is not a function".

I've tried a lot of different ways to export it like:

- module.exports= io_test(server);
- module.exports= io_fin;
- module.exports= io_test.listen(server);
- etc..

And I feel like I'm doing I've missed a key concept of the sockets, because I'm totally stuck !
Sorry for this "newbye" issue, but I feel like I would really use some help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`let yoyo = require('socket.io')` This line is requiring, *a new*, `socket.io` function.

You're exporting in your `server.js`, so you should import from *that file* like:

```
// assuming the file you're importing from is in the same folder as server.js
let yoyo = require('./server');
```